# Save list of object into table using automapper asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

This is my DTO

```
public class Part1
{
    public Part1()
    {
        Value = new List<ValueList>();
    }

    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public List<ValueList> Value { get; set; }
}
public class ValueList
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my table structure and I want to save above dto into below dto using automapper

```
public class Part1
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code with LINQ, without AM, then we'll see how AM can help.

Comment: I not able to create LINQ in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know how to make the list map to singel string in the new model?

You can check my demo, in mapper profile, define the three values to map:

```
public class AutoMapping : Profile
{
    public AutoMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<Part1, Part1DTO>()    //Part1DTO is your below model
             .ForMember(x => x.Value1, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.Value[0].Value1))
             .ForMember(x => x.Value2, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.Value[0].Value2))
             .ForMember(x => x.Value3, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.Value[0].Value3));
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Part1 part1= new Part1()
        {
            Id=1,
            Value=new List<ValueList> { new ValueList { Value1=1,Value2="b",Value3="c"} }
        };  //define old model 
        var result = _mapper.Map<Part1DTO>(part1);  // map to new
        return View(result);
    }
```

Don't forget to add this in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

Result:

[image]